# "Unsaved changes" warning not showing up for custom text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, nicedit

I'm using [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) in a form for my company's webpage.

Before using NicEdit, we just used a regular textarea input box. If we typed in any textarea boxes, before leaving the page we would get an "unsaved changes" prompt. Now I'm not longer receiving that prompt since changing to NicEdit. I wanted to see if there's a way to create a prompt specifically for the NicEdit textarea boxes.

Here's the coding for the prompt that is being used for the textarea boxes. Not sure if it's commonly used because the person that previously built this site was not very organized.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var warnMessage = "";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(':input').change(function() {
                window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                    if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
                }
            });
            $('input:submit').click(function(e) {
                warnMessage = null;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Here is the NicEdit script info:

```html
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);
</script>
```

Comment: investigate `onUnload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

Comment: Chances are, the NicEdit is not using a regular input/textarea element (because of its WYSIWYG nature). You will need to check their documentation if the editor emits some kind of change/input events which you can listen to, to perform the logic you intended. However, NicEdit does not appear to be in active development and it's probably a better idea to explore other WYISWYG editor, such as [Quill](https://quilljs.com/).

Comment: The warning for unsaved changed is not a standard behaviour with textboxes. You have to listen for 'beforeUnload' event on the window object and do the checks manually

Comment: @KiJéy OP never implied that he's relying on a standard feature. He's listening to the `change` event, which the NicEdit editor is not emitting.